# Refresh the user interface after uploading an image with AWS/S3 in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, amazon-s3, next.js

I hope that someone can help me. I have built an image upload which uses presigned urls provided by s3 to upload the image. So far it all works more than perfect but the ui is not updated after uploading. I have tested everything from revalidatePath, trpc utils etc. How can I get my ui to be updated after uploading?

Server Action:

```
"use server";

import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options";
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import prisma from "./db/prisma";

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION!,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY!,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
  },
});

const acceptedTypes = [
  "image/jpeg",
  "image/png",
  "image/gif",
  "image/svg+xml",
  "image/webp",
  "image/tiff",
  "image/bmp",
];
const maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5MB

export async function getSignedURL(
  type: string,
  size: number,
  checksum: string,
  teamId: string
) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!session) {
    return { error: { message: "You must be signed in to upload a file" } };
  }
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: session.user?.email!,
    },
  });

  if (!acceptedTypes.includes(type)) {
    return { error: { message: "File type not supported" } };
  }

  if (size > maxFileSize) {
    return { error: { message: "File size too large" } };
  }
  const putObjectCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Key: `${teamId}-logo`,
    ContentType: type,
    ContentLength: size,
    ChecksumSHA256: checksum,
    Metadata: {
      user: user?.id!,
    },
  });

  const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, putObjectCommand, {
    expiresIn: 60,
  });

  const updatedTeam = await prisma.team.update({
    where: {
      id: teamId,
    },
    data: {
      logo: signedUrl.split("?")[0],
    },
  });
  return { success: { url: signedUrl } };
}
```

Ui:

```
"use client";
import { trpc } from "@/app/_trpc/client";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { getSignedURL } from "@/lib/s3-team-logo";
import { Cloud, File, Image } from "lucide-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import { Progress } from "../ui/progress";

interface TeamImageProps {
  teamId: string;
  refetchTeam: () => void;
}

const TeamImage = ({ teamId, refetchTeam }: TeamImageProps) => {
  const utils = trpc.useUtils();
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data: team } = trpc.teamRouter.getTeam.useQuery({
    id: teamId,
  });
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const startSimulatedProgress = () => {
    setUploadProgress(0);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setUploadProgress((prevProgress) => {
        if (prevProgress >= 95) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return prevProgress;
        }
        return prevProgress + 5;
      });
    }, 500);

    return interval;
  };

  const computeSHA256 = async (file: File) => {
    const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", buffer);
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
    const hashHex = hashArray
      .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
      .join("");
    return hashHex;
  };
  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger>
        <Image className="h-4 w-4" />
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <Dropzone
            multiple={false}
            maxSize={4 * 1024 * 1024}
            onDrop={async (acceptedFiles) => {
              setIsUploading(true);

              const progressInterval = startSimulatedProgress();

              //handle file upload
              try {
                const checksum = await computeSHA256(acceptedFiles[0]);
                const signedURLResult = await getSignedURL(
                  acceptedFiles[0].type,
                  acceptedFiles[0].size,
                  checksum,
                  team?.id!
                );
                if (signedURLResult.error) {
                  toast(
                    `Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es erneut und achte auf Dateityp und -größe.`
                  );
                  clearInterval(progressInterval);
                  setUploadProgress(0);
                  return;
                }
                const url = signedURLResult.success?.url;

                if (!url) {
                  console.log("second");
                  return;
                }

                await fetch(url, {
                  cache: "no-cache",
                  method: "PUT",
                  body: acceptedFiles[0],
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": acceptedFiles[0].type,
                  },
                });
                clearInterval(progressInterval);
                setUploadProgress(100);
                toast("Upload erfolgreich");
                setOpen(false);
              } catch (error) {
                toast(`Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: ${error}`);
              }
            }}
          >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, acceptedFiles }) => (
              <div
                {...getRootProps()}
                className="m-4 h-64 rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-300"
              >
                <div className="flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="dropzone-file"
                    className="flex h-full w-full cursor-pointer flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100"
                  >
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pb-6 pt-5">
                      <Cloud className="mb-2 h-6 w-6 text-gray-500" />
                      <p className="mb-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-700">
                        <span className="font-semibold">
                          Team Logo hinzufügen
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        Logo hier hin ziehen oder klicken
                      </p>
                      <p className="text-xs text-gray-500">Bild (max. 4MB)</p>
                    </div>
                    {acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles[0] ? (
                      <div className="flex max-w-xs items-center divide-x divide-gray-200 overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-white outline outline-[1px] outline-gray-200">
                        <div className="grid h-full place-items-center px-3 py-2">
                          <File className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-500" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="h-full truncate px-3 py-2 text-sm">
                          {acceptedFiles[0].name}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ) : null}

                    {isUploading ? (
                      <div className="mx-auto mt-4 w-full max-w-xs">
                        <Progress
                          value={uploadProgress}
                          className="h-1 w-full bg-gray-200"
                        />
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default TeamImage;
```